How to add usb0 (gadget ethernet interface) to a network bridge using systemd-networkd
I have a working systemd network bridge br0 that I setup by creating the following two files:
# cat /etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge

# cat /etc/systemd/network/br0.network
[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
Address=192.168.0.1/24

I then added eth1 (a usb-eth adapter) as well as a dummy interface to the bridge like so:
# cat /etc/systemd/network/dummy0.network
[Match]
Name=dummy0
[Network]
Bridge=br0

# cat /etc/systemd/network/eth1.network
[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
Bridge=br0

This works well for what I need; it allows me to use the address 192.168.0.1 even if the usb-eth adapter is not plugged in and eth1 is not in the interface list.
I added a USB gadget ethernet connection by calling modprobe g_ether which creates the interface usb0, that automatically comes up with address 192.168.11.1 and provides a DHCP address to the device connected to it over USB.
I tried to add usb0 to the bridge like dummy0 and eth1, by creating this file:
# cat /etc/systemd/network/usb0.network
[Match]
Name=usb0
[Network]
Bridge=br0

But it still comes up with its default address 192.168.11.1 and still serves a DHCP address to its remote connection.
Calling bridge link I still only see dummy0 and eth1.
Any way to disable this default behavior so I can add it to my bridge?
